# How to assign PHP expression to a JavaScript variable?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I know it seems like a daft question but I am getting synatx error `var imagename = ;`. in the code below.

```
 var imagename = <?php if (isset($_SESSION['imagename'])) echo json_encode($_SESSION['imagename']); ?>;
```

var imagename is a javascript variable but why am I getting this error? is it because ; is in the wrong place or am I messing a ; or have I added to many ;. I just can't seem to figure it out.

Thanks

Comment: BTW, you need quotes wrapped to the php block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for something like this:

```
var imagename = <?php echo json_encode(isset($_SESSION['imagename']) ? $_SESSION['imagename'] : null); ?>
```

See http://php.net/ternary#language.operators.comparison.ternary for more info on how the ternary operator works.

Answer (score 2):

You have no else clause, so if that session variable isn't set, you end up generating your empty assignment.

```
var imagename = <?php if (isset($_SESSION['imagename'])) { echo json_encode($_SESSION['imagename']); } else { echo "''"; } ?>;
```

Comment: Good catch. I missed that he was json encoding the session var.

Answer (score 0):

The error is probably occuring when `$_SESSION['imagename']` does not exist. You should add an else clause for when this happens.